# Unable to program ATmega168: bad AVRISPmkII connection status: MOSI fail

Tags: atmega, avrdude, icsp

I’m trying to program an ATmega168 using an AVRISPmkii via the 6-pin ICSP on a board I “designed” (my first).

I have VCC connected to a PSU and the AVRISPmkii connected to the ICSP header. The AVRISPmkii’s LED is solid green at this point. When I try to program it using avrdude the LED on the AVRISPmkii changes to flashing red and avrdude reports:

```
bad AVRISPmkII connection status: MOSI fail
```

The chip works fine on the board (it runs the program on it properly, responding to inputs and doing the right thing for outputting to a display), as I’d previously programmed it on a breadboard. It has the Arduino bootloader on it, in case that’s relevant.

The ABRISPmkii is able to program the same chip if I move the chip from the custom board onto an Arduino Diecimla board, using the exact same avrdude command.

I’ve checked the board for shorts. I’ve checked for continuity on the 6 connections, from the pins on the headers to the pins on the chip, 5V and GND.

I presume this means there’s something wrong with the board design, but I can’t see what I might have done wrong.

This is the main part of the schematic:

[image: Schematic]

The full avrdude command line and output is:

```
$ /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf  -patmega168 -cavrisp2 -Pusb -Uflash:w:/var/folders/v9/qn7wvjqs18v6g5j_wlxxs2pw0000gn/T/build4459692069199443819.tmp/badminton_scoreboard_beep.cpp.hex:i  -vvvv

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 18:52:52
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is “/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/dave/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : avrisp2
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRISP mkII, serno: 000200033610
avrdude: usbdev_open(): using read endpoint 0x82
avrdude: Sent: . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [01] . [00] . [0a] A [41] V [56] R [52] I [49] S [53] P [50] _ [5f] M [4d] K [4b] 2 [32] 
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): found AVRISP mkII programmer
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA168
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no        512    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     16384  128    128  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500V2
         Description     : Atmel AVR ISP mkII
         Programmer Model: AVRISP mkII
avrdude: Sent: . [03] . [90] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] . [00] . [01] 
avrdude: Sent: . [03] . [91] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] . [00] . [01] 
avrdude: Sent: . [03] . [92] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] . [00] . [0c] 
         Hardware Version: 1
         Firmware Version Master : 1.12
avrdude: Sent: . [03] . [94] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] . [00] . [00] 
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
avrdude: Sent: . [03] . [98] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] . [00] . [06] 
         SCK period      : 8.00 us

avrdude: Sent: . [10] . [c8] d [64] . [19]   [20] . [00] S [53] . [03] . [ac] S [53] . [00] . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] . [c0] 
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
avrdude: Sent: . [03] . [a1] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] . [00] . [01] 
avrdude: stk500v2_program_enable(): bad AVRISPmkII connection status: MOSI fail
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: Sent: . [11] . [01] . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [11] . [00] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Any idea what I might have done wrong or what further troubleshooting steps I could try?

Comment: Do you have anything connected to the MISO/MOSI/SCK pins of the mcu (any kind of load)?

Comment: No, I don’t use SPI or those digital pins for anything else.

Comment: Try putting a Capacitor between Aref and Ground( if possible do try disconnecting Aref from Avcc). In past I'd encountered similar situation and this helped me.

Comment: I can try that. I thought I’d read I should tie it to 5V since I wasn’t using the ADC, but now I can’t find where I read that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would AREF being tied 5V interfere with ICSP programming?

Comment: Tried disconnecting AREF and still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solder bridge between MOSI and GND that was causing this issue.

Comment: Where? Which / how many pins were affected?

Comment: Between MOSI and GND where I'd soldered the ICSP header. I don't know how I missed it before.

Comment: Um, please put that detail in your *answer*, not as a comment. I was trying to (gently) imply that your answer was vague and not necessarily beneficial to someone looking for context.